# write matrix to one column of a table - matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

```
>> x = 'x';
>> y = [1,2,3,4];
>> T = table({x},{y});
>> writetable(T,'T.txt','Delimiter','\t')
```

when I open `T.txt` the different elements of `y` are written in separate columns:

```
Var1    Var2_1  Var2_2  Var2_3  Var2_4
x          1       2       3      4
```

is there a way to put them in one single column? eg:

```
Var1  Var2
x     [1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating that table, you can make `Var2` a character array instead. Now if you write that table, you will get your expected result.

```
T = table({x}, mat2str(y));
writetable(T,'T.txt','Delimiter','\t');
```

**Result:**

```
Var1    Var2
x   [1 2 3 4]
```